# why the string of allclear changed after sprintf( command, "rm %s", newfile )?

Tags: gdb, printf

why the string of allclear changed after sprintf( command, "rm %s", newfile ),I thind "command" has not relationship with "allclear"

```
(gdb) p allclear
$18 = "/home/river/Desktop/stage2/bin/config/02_allclear_12HD", '\000' <repeats 45 times>
(gdb) p &allclear
$19 = (char (*)[100]) 0xbfffea0c
(gdb) p &command
$20 = (char (*)[50]) 0xbfffe9da
**(gdb) n
65      sprintf( command, "rm %s", newfile );**
(gdb) p allclear 
$21 = "/home/river/Desktop/stage2/bin/config/02_allclear_12HD", '\000' <repeats 45 times>
(gdb) n
66      if( argc < 1) return 1;
**(gdb) p allclear 
$22 = "001005/controlpage\000/stage2/bin/config/02_allclear_12HD", '\000' <repeats 45 times>**
(gdb) p $allclear 
$23 = void
(gdb) p &allclear 
$24 = (char (*)[100]) 0xbfffea0c
(gdb) p newfile
$25 = "/home/river/Desktop/stage2/test_case/01_SES/SES001005/controlpage", '\000' <repeats 34 times>
(gdb) p &command
$26 = (char (*)[50]) 0xbfffe9da
```

some part of my code is :

```
char allclear[MAXPATHSIZE];
memset( allclear, 0, MAXPATHSIZE);
sprintf( allclear, "%s/config/02_allclear_12HD", curfilepathdir);

char command[MAXCOMMAMDSIZE];

memset( command, 0, MAXCOMMAMDSIZE);
sprintf( command, "rm %s", newfile );
```

Comment: Perhaps the length of `newfile` is too great for your `command` buffer ? Hint use `snprintf` to prevent buffer overruns such as this.

Comment: @PaulR There is no "perhaps" about it: the info is right there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From GDB output, it's pretty clear that `MAXCOMMANDSIZE` is 50.

How long is `"rm /home/river/Desktop/stage2/test_case/01_SES/SES001005/controlpage"` ?

You might want to read up on [buffer overflows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow), and start using safer variant of `sprintf`, namely `snprintf`.